# Why aria2c ignore the "title" in a URL?

Tags: url, aria2

```
E:\软件\下载工具\aria2-1.34.0-win-64bit-build1>aria2c.exe "https://r3---sn-5hne6nsd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1610124847&ei=zzn4X8juIIap1gLM2pKwBA&ip=103.219.154.170&id=o-AFFclWq4Wy2bYeOeytzaVBhyN6lujxK37xBFtEURytYX&itag=137&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=gh&mm=31%2C26&mn=sn-5hne6nsd%2Csn-4g5ednll&ms=au%2Conr&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=24&initcwndbps=34172500&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=jksNT2iucayKnZZEXcRV7CoF&gir=yes&clen=42985655&otfp=1&dur=277.243&lmt=1608060512851987&mt=1610102921&fvip=6&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=6216222&n=FqW-lOTnAYXfzQ&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cotfp%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgRnnQRQvsPPFegF2XKaFIZMvc-t59kP2QorLeDHVBUqcCIQDQRPD3znoat1a764aXFV2M16wIOJv__9nRd6aS5ZVOoA%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgU7nnu3l7NgbpAfRlrxmolOJwQqwsl1deikNRVjCRnvsCIQDQoT9UjRsYk1rGqZvMsTDnGVnth0i44cagdCQ6Fqdfyw%3D%3D&title=%E8%92%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AF%E3%83%AB%E3%83%84%20_%20Eve%20%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB%E3%80%8E%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%82%BC%E3%81%A8%E8%99%8E%E3%81%A8%E9%AD%9A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%80%8F%E4%B8%BB%E9%A1%8C%E6%AD%8C%20(%E3%83%94%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8E)" --all-proxy=127.0.0.1:10809

01/08 19:05:03 [NOTICE] Downloading 1 item(s)
[#770791 0B/0B CN:1 DL:0B]
01/08 19:05:04 [NOTICE] File already exists. Renamed to E:/软件/下载工具/aria2-1.34.0-win-64bit-build1/videoplayback.1.

01/08 19:05:04 [NOTICE] Allocating disk space. Use --file-allocation=none to disable it. See --file-allocation option in man page for more details.
 *** Download Progress Summary as of Fri Jan 08 19:06:03 2021 ***
=======================================================================================================================
[#770791 21MiB/40MiB(53%) CN:1 DL:431KiB ETA:45s]
FILE: E:/软件/下载工具/aria2-1.34.0-win-64bit-build1/videoplayback.1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 *** Download Progress Summary as of Fri Jan 08 19:07:04 2021 ***
=======================================================================================================================
[#770791 40MiB/40MiB(97%) CN:1 DL:506KiB ETA:1s]
FILE: E:/软件/下载工具/aria2-1.34.0-win-64bit-build1/videoplayback.1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[#770791 40MiB/40MiB(99%) CN:1 DL:486KiB]
01/08 19:07:05 [NOTICE] Download complete: E:/软件/下载工具/aria2-1.34.0-win-64bit-build1/videoplayback.1

Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
770791|OK  |   346KiB/s|E:/软件/下载工具/aria2-1.34.0-win-64bit-build1/videoplayback.1

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
```

The example above.
The URL actually has a parameter "title" ,but aria2 just ignores it.
So what can I do?
P.S. I'm not willing to use the `--input-file` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aria2c` does not parse the parameters to the URL or interprets them.

You can specify the name of the output file using [`-o`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-o) option. If the file name is not specified, aria2 uses the latest path component of the URL which is `videoplayback` in your case.